# CouchDB replication stopped after a _conflict

Tags: couchdb, revision-history, revisions

I have a user that today is not replicating the new documents that the others users are adding on my `CoucDB` database, in other words the user **A** does not see the docuemnts that the  users  **B, C** is adding every day.

I have seen the last document added from the user **A** to CouchDB and I have seen that the document has a new field

> _conflicts: ["2-17d3fcec15fbe3b1eed3e7f8a14eae35"]}

[image]

I guess the conflict is in the second revision of the document, Is not it? I have 7 revision about the same document
my question is How I can resolve it? How I can remove this conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CouchDB does not attempt to merge the conflicting revision.**

Your application dictates how the merging should be done.

see http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/replication/conflicts.html

but generaly speaking the suggested algorithm to fetch a document with conflict resolution:

- Get document via `GET docid?conflicts=true request`;
- For each member in the _conflicts array `call GET docid?rev=xxx`. If any errors occur at this stage, restart from step 1. (There could be a race where someone else has already resolved this conflict and deleted that rev)
- Perform application-specific merging
- Write _bulk_docs with an update to the first rev and deletes of the other revs.

alos see the version on [ruby](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication_and_conflicts)

Comment: in all the revision the documents are equal, just change the revion field and id field, so could I delete the revision doc and just keep the last one, I mean I have revison 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 I will deleted 1,2,3,4,5,6 and keep the revision 7